# Spring boot application war not working, Getting 404 when deplying on tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
public class AppController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(){
    return "Hello World";
}
}
```

When I deploy the war I am getting 404.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn3uR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqmjb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etiVM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwLCp.png)

I created the war using mvn clean install or mvn package,and deployed on tomcat server, but getting same 404 not found.

Is there any way I can deploy spring boot application war to tomcat?

Comment: check under the tomcat webapps folder to see how (if) it has been deployed.

Comment: yes, war file is there with name "demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war".  and it's deplyed as shown in screenshot

Comment: Below the demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOTdirectory is the classes there? Also check your log file (catalina.out) to see if there is a reason that it did not deploy.

Comment: classes are there, and not getting any error in catalina. Is there any configuration needs to be done for springboot application war deployment.

Comment: Have you tried just running it rather than deploying to a tomcat server? Test to see if that works first?

Comment: Also are you missing `<start-class>com.xxx.demo.DemoApplication</start-class>`  see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_tomcat_deployment.htm

Comment: Application is running fine with intellij on embedded tomcat server, also tried with start-class but still same,

Answer (score -1):

Is there any way I can deploy spring boot application war to tomcat?
you can run this command in command prompt.
mvnw spring-boot:run

Note:
May be you should try this url:
http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: This command will run with embedded server, but I want to run on another tomcat server , Sorry to say but this url: http://localhost:8080/test also not working